# How to view as string when datacolumn[row][0] return system.byte

Tags: c#, mysql

The problem is related to mysql and c#

I have a stored procedure which returns out put of a query 
The query has concatenated columns  as first column and other individual columns

When i access the data column as dt.rows[i][0] it returns as System.byte[]

Even i tried to write it to file but it always write as System.byte[] in file

I tried to convert it to byte array using 
byte[] b= (byte[])dt.Rows[i][0];

It gives exception as cannot convert string to byte[]

I tried to add all values as string in a list like

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    list.Add(row[0].ToString());
                }
```

And writing list[i] to file writes System.byte[] to file

Any Idea how to over come this problem

Other columns are accessed and displayed normally, this is the case only with first column which has cancatenated values from multiple columns

like this

> SELECT CONCAT ('390',         DATE (t5.InventoryDate)         ,t5.SKUorItem       ) AS
>   PK,
>       t5.CustomerID, t5.entityID, t5.inventoryDate, t5.SKUorItem, t5.Category, t5.inventory FROM

Comment: Well presumably the data column is binary data...

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested the code but hopefully you get the ideea.
Trasform each octet into a number and cast the number as a char.

```
int character = 0;
int bitValue = 1;
int count = 0;
string result = "";

for (int i = row[0].Length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    character += row[0][i] * bitValue;
    bitValue *= 2;
    count++;
    if(count == 7)
    {
         count = 0;
         character= 0;
         bitValue = 1;
         result += (char) character;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for replying to my query
Probably the solution provided will also work but i haven't tested it

I found the solution as
Instead of this phraze

> SELECT CONCAT ('390', DATE (t5.InventoryDate) ,t5.SKUorItem ) AS PK, t5.CustomerID, t5.entityID, t5.inventoryDate, t5.SKUorItem, t5.Category, t5.inventory FROM

I modified it like this

> SELECT CONCAT ('390', cast(DATE (t5.InventoryDate) as char) ,cast(t5.SKUorItem as char)) AS PK, t5.CustomerID, t5.entityID, t5.inventoryDate, t5.SKUorItem, t5.Category, t5.inventory FROM

Casting converts the date and time value, or any value other than string to char
So mysql returns String instead of byte[]

But once again thanks for your response

regards
Afzal

Answer (score 0):

After many hours i create Encode and Serialize and this returns a string with the src that you apply to the img.

```
string img_src = data.Rows[0].IsNull("PHOTO") ? string.Format("") : string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", data.Rows[0]["PHOTO"].EncodeAndSerialize().Replace("\"", ""));

    public static string EncodeAndSerialize<T>(this T obj) where T : new()
            {
                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = new HtmlEncodeResolver(),
                    Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None
                };
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
            }
```